# Displaying a products attribute in a tab?

Tags: magento, tabs, attributes

I have created a new tab called “pdf” and the source code for it is in pdf.phtml, i have also created a new attribute called “PDF” how do i get this attribute to show up in my tab.

I have tried to use the description tab code however it references a method called getDescription to grab the description from magento and assign the variable to it.

How would i be able to do this with my pdf attribute so i can have a tab for my pdf files and if there isnt a file then display a message?? 
if this is unclear let me know as i have been trying this all day and have started to get frustrated with it.

Also no links to extensions please as my mangers want me to hard code.

This tab is in my product page not admin page just to clear up any misunderstandings

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For create new tab for particular attribute Go to admin > Catalog > Attribute >
    Manage Attribute Set and click on your set where you will show the tab.

```
Then "Add New" in Groups block, Set your tab name Like PDF File, Then Drag and Drop 
your attribute into "Unassigned Attributes" to Groups block.

Then save and check you new tab automatic create with your name or attribute.

Thanks
```

Comment: will try this tomorrow and let you know how i get on.

thank you in advance

Comment: Think you misunderstood my problem i want to add an Attribute to a tab on my product page not the admin page. But thank you anyways.

Comment: Okay fine sorry for this, you will use this extension, I have also used.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-attachments-extension.html

Answer (score 0):

Okay fine sorry for this, you will use this extension, I have also used.

```
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-attachments-extension.html
```

Comment: Ok thank you i will try this extension tomorrow. Thank you for your reply though.